# Row header not appearing in a Matrix with a single value

Tags: powerbi

At the moment I have a simple matrix with dates for columns and a single value. It looks like this:

[image]

You can see there is no row header for the single value. However, as soon as I add another value, I get row headers for both values.

[image]

I do have Show on rows turned on. How can I get the row header to appear when I have just a single value?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no clean way to do this at the moment.

[This Power BI Community post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Format-Matrix-show-row-headers-with-only-one-value/td-p/1291395) is essentially the same question but doesn't have any solutions other than using a title or text boxes as a workaround.